# 'It would have been better if' grammatical issue

Tags: conditionals, conditional-perfect

I am confused what is the correct usage of this

> It would have been better if government banned the production of firecrackers
>
> It would have been better if government had banned the production of firecrackers.

If both are correct then what is the difference between two.

Comment: "It would be better if the government banned the production of firecrackers".The sentence refers to the future. Your second sentence refers to the past, expressing regret.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The independent clause

**It would have been better...**

refers to a point in time in the *past* when a condition was not true.

To mark the fact that this condition was contrary to the reality, the tense is shifted towards the past relative to the point-in-time in question.  A past time which is prior to a point in time also in the past is marked by the past perfect, **had banned**.

**It would have been better if the Donner Party *had brought* more rations along back in 1846.**

If you wish to refer to a condition that is contrary to fact *now*, at this moment, the independent clause becomes

**It *would be* better...**

and the tense of the condition shifts backwards in time relative to the present, and thus the simple past is used:

**It would be better if cigarette manufacturers *stopped* marketing to children in the Pacific Rim.**